# Macbook Pro Airplay 2 support for Sonos Play:5 Speakers

Tags: macbook-pro, airplay

I am considering purchasing [Sonos Play:5](https://www.sonos.com/en/shop/play5.html) which advertises support for Airplay 2. Will I be able to stream any audio I want from my Macbook Pro to the speaker?

All the examples I can find online seem to indicate support with the Homepod but I am unsure if this is a Homepod specific feature or an Airplay 2 feature.

I am looking at the following scenarios:

- Netflix on Safari
- Video files I have being played via VLC/MPV

Answer (score 1):

[image]

All speakers with this label on the packaging, you can stream to from your MacBook without a Home Pod.

AirPlay 2 will work on the Sonos Play 5 second generation.

> Enjoy AirPlay 2 on your entire Sonos system. Even though AirPlay 2 is only supported on Sonos One, Beam, Playbase **and Play:5 (2nd generation)**, grouping your other speakers to any of these and you can use AirPlay across your entire home sound system.

([Source](https://blog.sonos.com/en-gb/airplay-is-here/))

From the [System Requirements:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208728#airplay2)

You can stream from:

> Mac or PC with iTunes 12.8 or later

To update your iTunes version see [here.](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201352#mac)

Answer (score 0):

Before making the purchase, I'd advise you to go through the following Apple support article and blog post from Sonos:

- [AirPlay system requirements](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208728#airplay2)
- [An Update on Sonos Speaker Support For AirPlay 2](https://blog.sonos.com/en/airplay2-coming/)

As per Apple support document, you should be able to use AirPlay 2 with a Mac running iTunes.

As per the Sonos blog post, Play:5 will support AirPlay 2.